# How to relocate Netbeans' %USERPROFILE%\.m2 directory?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, directory

I can move the `.netbeans` directory from my user directory but I cannot find how to move the `.m2` directory.
Changing Netbeans'user home worked on 7.0.1, but now I upgraded to 7.1.1 and the same configuration changes as before aren't cutting it.

Is there some special way to move the `.m2` folder?

Comment: chk this out http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Set-alternate-location-for-m2-td89273.html

Comment: I've already found pages like that. Those pages however are modifying the settings file within the %userprofile%\.m2 directory. I don't want the directory there in the first place since program files and folders don't belong directly in %userprofile% in Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.1\java\maven\conf\settings.xml

Changed localRepository in this file and it finally worked. Can't tell you how frustrating this has been.

Comment: @Richard any idea where can I do so for netbeans 6.9

Comment: @XCoder I assume it would be in the same NetBeans 6.9\java\maven\conf\settings.xml file. Is there a reason you don't upgrade though? I remember seeing improvements between 6 and 7.

Comment: @RichardRobertson It's not there in case of 6.9 seems like I have to upgrade. I don't prefer updating because I'm waiting for 7.3 to move out of beta so that I can directly upgrade to html5 + css3 support.

Comment: @XCoder Just to satisfy my curiosity, are you wanting to move it because it's in the profile folder like I encountered or because you just want a different location?

Comment: I just want a different location.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the [Maven guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) refers to everything (settings, repository, ...) as in "`${user.home}/.../`", the official way a new `user.home` for Maven.

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.home=/new/user/home
```

If it isn't working for some reason with NetBeans 7.1.1, a temporary workaround would be using a [junction (Windows Xp)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) or a [`mklink` (Windows Vista or Seven)](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-an-mklink-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user) in order to redirect the .m2 directory to another path.

Comment: That's not actually doing anything even though I know it's supposed to.

Comment: @RichardRobertson Do you mean that, if you are doing the symlink, you don't see the `.m2` content at the other location (you just symlinked to)?

Comment: I don't want a link, hard or soft because I don't want a file entry directly in my user folder in the first place. By not doing anything, I mean it continues to drop the folder directly in my user folder.

Comment: Figured it out finally. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 2):

My little bit to this theme (NetBeans ver. 8.0.2):

Services -> Maven -> Local -> Properties -> "Local repository path"

[image: Screenshot with settings]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10303614)

Comment: @ivarni Sure, it seems much better so, but I don't have a permission to "include" pictures in my posts - I'm "new registered":) But thanks for your Redaktion!

Comment: Someone edited and fixed the image it seems so no worries. That comment was automatically generated from a review (this site gets a lot of answers containing nothing but a link).

Answer (score 1):

Just add local repository bath in setting.xml file in your maven home
in the case of NetBeans you need to edit Netbeans home folder in java folder

```
d:\netbeans-8.2\java\maven\conf\settings.xml

<localRepository>d:\moh\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was set properly environment variables on run Netbeans. Important is variable **HOME**.

Tested on versions: Windows 10, Netbeans 8.1, Maven 3.3.9

```
set JAVA_HOME=X:\apps\jdk1.7.0_79
set HOME=X:\userhome
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
start X:\apps\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -J-Duser.home="%HOME%" --userdir "%HOME%\nbsettings" --cachedir "%HOME%\nbcache" --jdkhome "%JAVA_HOME%" --locale en
```